# Workflow never get from "Not Started" to "In progress"

Tags: workflow

I have  setup a list with a document review workflow(Out of box). If I run the workflow with 1 or 2 parallel users it appears to work. However, If I submit the workflow with the 10 parallel users(distributed group) then some of them never get from "Not Started" to "In progress" and they show write locked by workflow forever.